# How are Local Shopware Plugin composer.json Dependencies Managed?

Tags: php, composer-php, shopware

In a Shopware system, there's a main `composer.json` file.  This manages the main project dependencies. In addition to this, Shopware [plugins require you to add a `composer.json` file](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-base-guide). If these plugins are added to the system via the main `composer.json` file, then the dependencies in a plugin's `composer.json` file will end up in the root level `vendor/` folder.  This I understand.

However, it appears that plugins can also be installed locally outside of the `vendor` folder, in either

- `./custom/plugins` or
- `./custom/static-plugins`

When a plugin is installed *locally*, how should its dependencies be managed?

Is the intent that, when installing a plugin locally you'll also add its dependencies to the *main* `composer.json` file?  Or is there a way to tell shopware

> Hey, install this plugin's dependencies

Also -- how do the `./custom/plugins/*/packages` folders enter into this?  It's my vague understanding that these are for *private* plugin dependencies, but I'm not sure what that means or how that code should be managed

Or am I misunderstanding the intent behind these local folders, and the expectation in Shopware 6 is that all plugins should be installed via your main `composer.json` file and the `custom/` folders are just legacy?

Or some other thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your plugin lives within the `custom/static-plugins` folder, you can just `composer require my/plugin` from the root. So that's the way to use composer plugins within your project. Shopware is then searching for the composer plugin within the [custom/static-plugins/* repository](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/6.4/composer.json#L45-L51).

Take a look at the [Require project plugins](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/installation-updates/composer#require-project-plugins) section within the Docs on how to deal with requiring composer plugins.

Within the `custom/plugins` folder you have all your store plugins. That's also the reason why the content of the `custom/plugins` folder [is not committed](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/6.4/.gitignore#L1-L2) to your git repo. Because plugins within `custom/plugins` are coming from the Shopware store. However: You can still also just place your plugins within the `custom/plugins` folder if you want to.

Regarding `custom/plugins/*/packages`: You're right. Take a look at the [adding private composer dependencies](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-composer-dependencies#adding-private-composer-dependencies) section within the docs.

Comment: Are the "private dependencies" real private to a plugin or would they conflict with each other, if two plugins ship conflicting versions of such dependencies?

Comment: if you install those two plugins with `composer require` in your root `composer.json`. there would be a conflict. or they would both use the version of one plugin. depending on how the requirements are defined

Comment: That makes sense and is useful Christopher.  I still have one big unanswered question.  If I have something like custom/plugins/SomePlugin/composer.json, is shopware doing anything to install the dependencies listed in `custom/plugins/SomePlugin/composer.json`?

Comment: No - You would need to ship the plugin with the whole vendor folder then, install the dependencies within your CI or just make a `composer install` within your plugin on the server manually.

Comment: "no" is not totally right here :-) you can also require your plugin in your Shopware composer. then the dependencies of your plugin will be resolved in the Shopware vendor directory and you do not need to ship them. but this is only practical if it is local plugin for your project. or it is public available on packagist or GitHub or so. if you want to publish the plugin in the store, you still need to ship the dependencies. but this will also change in a future major version. hopefully 6.5.0.0